# Web3 connecting to Infura

Tags: web3js, infura

[image]

installed web3
and follwed steps int he image

Comment: It is better if you include your code as text so it is easier to test.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to insert your infura application link with the full url including http / https? Try this way and check if the error has changed.

```
Example: new Web3('https://mainnet.infura.io/YOUR_APP_ID');
```